# How should I answer my own question if I have two solutions?

Tags: discussion

I have, with help, managed to solve my [own question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45526/). However, the solution I came up with was short (~15 lines of code) and perhaps more transparent -- at least for someone at my level.

Then, I got even more help with a much more elaborate solution which takes into account many other details (slightly outside the scope of the question) of what I wanted to do, but that solution is much longer (~100 lines) and I'm not sure that I could fully do it justice if I were to answer my question with that solution.

So my question here is basically what the best practice would be for a case like this. Should I answer with the simpler, but less effective, solution? Should I, instead, try and answer with the second longer solution? Or should I just not answer at all, since I did not come up with the solutions on my own?

Comment: You (and all users) are welcome to [self-answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) your own questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the more complex solution is a generalization/improvement of the simpler solution, then put both of them in the same post and explain how the former improves on the latter.  If they are qualitatively different approaches, it's okay to do two answer posts.

In any event, go ahead and cite who you got help from.